# How to formally define $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, definition

How to formally define $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

I suppose it's $\forall K\in\Bbb{R},\ \exists N\in\Bbb{R},\ x\gt N\implies f(x)\gt K$.

Could someone correct it?

Comment: What you have is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure this needs correction, it's an excellent working definition.

Comment: This is so googleable...

Comment: @EdwardJiang and others: Not correct; see my answer. CoolKid: Did you understand my answer or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is technically wrong, because you are missing the universal quantification of $x$. Without the quantifier, $x$ would be a free variable, which conventionally is interpreted essentially the same as an external quantification, which is on the outside. This is of course different from having the quantifier on the inside, because you cannot switch $\forall$ and $\exists$. The correct one is:
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

> $\forall k \in \rr\ ( \exists n \in \rr\ ( \forall x \in \rr\ ( x > n \imp f(x) > k ) ) )$

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the correct definition of $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty $